# Stripping whitespaces from a list inside the list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

[image]

I want to strip the white spaces present in the list inside of the tuple how can I do it ??? for e.g in first tuple's list " Bakery" has the whitespace I want to make it "Bakery"

```
for i in features:
  for j in i[1]:
    j = j.strip(' ')
```

I have tried this but failed.

> features = (83,
>     ['Fast Food',
>      ' Bakery',
>      ' Beverages',
>      ' Burgers',
>      ' Ice Cream',
>      ' Pizza',
>      ' Seafood',
>      ' Steaks',
>      ' Tea & Coffee',
>      ' Dessert',
>      'Batagram',
>      'Pakistan',
>      '1',
>      ' 23',
>      ' 26',
>      ' 37',
>      ' 44']),
>    (83,
>     ['Fast Food',
>      ' Bakery',
>      ' Beverages',
>      ' Burgers',
>      ' Ice Cream',
>      ' Pizza',
>      ' Seafood',
>      ' Steaks',
>      ' Tea & Coffee',
>      ' Dessert',
>      'Bhalwal',
>      'Pakistan',
>      '1',
>      ' 23',
>      ' 26',
>      ' 37',
>      ' 44']),
>    (83,
>     ['Fast Food',
>      ' Bakery',
>      ' Beverages',
>      ' Burgers',
>      ' Ice Cream',
>      ' Pizza',
>      ' Seafood',
>      ' Steaks',
>      ' Tea & Coffee',
>      ' Dessert',
>      'Burewala',
>      'Pakistan',
>      '1',
>      ' 23',
>      ' 26',
>      ' 37',
>      ' 44']),
>    (83,
>     ['Fast Food',
>      ' Bakery',
>      ' Beverages',
>      ' Burgers',
>      ' Ice Cream',
>      ' Pizza',
>      ' Seafood',
>      ' Steaks',
>      ' Tea & Coffee',
>      ' Dessert',
>      'Chakwal',
>      'Pakistan',
>      '1',
>      ' 23',
>      ' 26',
>      ' 37',
>      ' 44'])

Comment: Please, read about [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: don't post images like this it's unreadable. And providing some attempt is also useful to help us help you

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre just added the code that I tried

Comment: Add `feature` variable data. It can contain just few rows. And fix indentation in your code.

Comment: `j` is a new variable, you're not changing your list by reassigning to it. It's a duplicate now.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How Can I reassign the value??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for tup in features:
    lst = [i.strip() for i in tup[1]]
    tup = tup[0] + lst
```

If I understand correctly, this will iterate over each tuple in your list, and replace the list - index 1 - with a `str.strip()` versin for each item

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach. Using `str.strip`

**Ex:**

```
features = (83, ['Fast Food', ' Bakery', ' Beverages', ' Burgers', ' Ice Cream', ' Pizza', ' Seafood', ' Steaks', ' Tea & Coffee', ' Dessert', 'Batagram', 'Pakistan', '1', ' 23', ' 26', ' 37', ' 44']), (83, ['Fast Food', ' Bakery', ' Beverages', ' Burgers', ' Ice Cream', ' Pizza', ' Seafood', ' Steaks', ' Tea & Coffee', ' Dessert', 'Bhalwal', 'Pakistan', '1', ' 23', ' 26', ' 37', ' 44']), (83, ['Fast Food', ' Bakery', ' Beverages', ' Burgers', ' Ice Cream', ' Pizza', ' Seafood', ' Steaks', ' Tea & Coffee', ' Dessert', 'Burewala', 'Pakistan', '1', ' 23', ' 26', ' 37', ' 44']), (83, ['Fast Food', ' Bakery', ' Beverages', ' Burgers', ' Ice Cream', ' Pizza', ' Seafood', ' Steaks', ' Tea & Coffee', ' Dessert', 'Chakwal', 'Pakistan', '1', ' 23', ' 26', ' 37', ' 44'])
features = [(i, [j.strip() for j in k]) for i, k in features]
print(features)
```

**Output:**

```
[(83, ['Fast Food', 'Bakery', 'Beverages', 'Burgers', 'Ice Cream', 'Pizza', 'Seafood', 'Steaks', 'Tea & Coffee', 'Dessert', 'Batagram', 'Pakistan', '1', '23', '26', '37', '44']), (83, ['Fast Food', 'Bakery', 'Beverages', 'Burgers', 'Ice Cream', 'Pizza', 'Seafood', 'Steaks', 'Tea & Coffee', 'Dessert', 'Bhalwal', 'Pakistan', '1', '23', '26', '37', '44']), (83, ['Fast Food', 'Bakery', 'Beverages', 'Burgers', 'Ice Cream', 'Pizza', 'Seafood', 'Steaks', 'Tea & Coffee', 'Dessert', 'Burewala', 'Pakistan', '1', '23', '26', '37', '44']), (83, ['Fast Food', 'Bakery', 'Beverages', 'Burgers', 'Ice Cream', 'Pizza', 'Seafood', 'Steaks', 'Tea & Coffee', 'Dessert', 'Chakwal', 'Pakistan', '1', '23', '26', '37', '44'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehensions and mapping over each element of the list:

```
features = [(a, list(map(lambda y: y.strip(), b))) for a, b in features]
```